# vb.net conflict between textleave and datagrid click events

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In my screen, i have a datagrid view and text boxes. the datagrid view is filled with entries made in the text boxes. Entries are checked on the leave event of each text boxes. If there is an error, a message box proposes to correct or cancel the entry. when the user clicks on the datagrid view, triggered by the datagridview click event, data are retrieved from the row and displayed in the text boxes. from a text box, if the user clicks on the datagridview, with an error in the data entered in the text box and choose to cancel the data entry, the focus should be on the datagridview line clicked. But it seems that the cancel made by the messagebox prevents the datagrid view click event to occur. the consequence is that I am not able to retrieve the index of the selected line and cannot position the focus on this line if the user chooses to cancel the entry made. How to retrieve the index of the selected line in the datagrid click event despite the message box cancel made in the text leave event ? Sorry, it is really difficult to describe.

Comment: How about putting the validation into the `Validating` method on the TextBox and see how that affects your flow?

Comment: You should definitely be doing validation in the `Validating` event handler. If validation fails then you set `e.Cancel` to `True` and the user cannot leave that control. You have probably set all this up wrong in the first place. You should bind your data to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid and the individual controls.

Comment: thank you for your answers. I am using a bindingSource and bound it to the datagrid (datagrid.datasource = bs). How do I bound the datagrid and the text objects to the binding source ?